# Prevent Azure PowerShell Credentials from expiring?

Tags: powershell, azure

I need to take regular backups of a suite of VM’s in an Azure environment. I thought the obvious solution to this would be to use PowerShell to automate the process so have written a script to do just that. I want this to run on a schedule, unattended with no manual intervention. However, the problem I have is that every few days I get the error:

```
  Your Windows Azure credential in the Windows PowerShell session has expired. Please use Add-AzureAccount to login again.
```

Which means I have to re-run  Add-AzureAccount and sign back in through the associated popup and everything works again. Obviously this is no good and negates the benefit of doing this automation.

Is there any way I can prevent these credentials from expiring?

Thanks

Comment: There is no alternative friend

Answer (score 6):

Yes, by using certificate authentication instead. One of the drawbacks of using `Add-AzureAccount` is that the credentials expire from time to time. You could just run Add-AzureAccount again but certificate authentication would be best for you in this scenario.

Firstly, remove the current accounts you have registered in PowerShell using the `Remove-AzureAccount` cmdlet. Something like:

```
Remove-AzureAccount -Name name@account.onmicrosoft.com
```

This doesn't remove your account from Azure, just the reference you hold to it in your PowerShell console (from when you used `Add-AzureAccount`). Then you run

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
```

this will open a browser window, ask you to authenticate to your account and you'll download a file ending in .publishsettings

Then, in Azure PowerShell you run

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile -PublishSettingsFile <path_to_file>
```

which will import the certificates from the publishsettings file, allowing you to execute your scripts without using `Add-AzureAccount`.

You may also need to use `Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName <name_of_subscription>` if you happen to have more than one subscription.

Additionally, the following MSDN blog describes the process just as I have above. http://blogs.technet.com/b/ricardma/archive/2014/07/04/managing-azure-subscriptions-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: I should also add that Azure Backup now allows you to take backups of Azure VMs so you may want to look in to doing that instead of your script as it's likely to be quicker and more foolproof. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms/